# Pandas PeriodIndex Aggregate count to list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code

```
df.groupby(df.dt.to_period("M")).agg({'count'})
```

Original Data

```
238   2021-03-05
         ...
460   2020-01-10
461   2019-12-27
462   2019-12-19
463   2019-12-18
464   2019-12-17
Name: Transaction_Date, Length: 231, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Returned Data when printed

```
                      count
Transaction_Date
2019-12               8
2020-01              12
2020-02              15
2020-03              27
2020-04              18
2020-05              11
2020-06              12
2020-07               1
2020-08               2
2020-09              13
2020-10              24
2020-11              21
2020-12               7
2021-01              18
2021-02              23
2021-03
```

I tried `to_dict.values` `to_dict` and `to_series` but didnt work. Also cannot iterate Period Index

**Desired Outcome**

e.g: 2019-12

```
[{"Date": "2019-12", "count": 8},{},...]
```

Comment: How looks input data before your code? e.g. first 3 rows of `df`

Comment: @jezrael I added it to the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df.groupby(df['Transaction_Date'].dt.to_period("M")).agg({'count'}).reset_index()
```

---

First use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) for strings `YYYY-MM` with [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html), last use [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html):

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='20D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Transaction_Date': rng})  

df=df.groupby(df['Transaction_Date'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m")).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  Transaction_Date  count
0          2017-04      2
1          2017-05      1
2          2017-06      2
3          2017-07      1
4          2017-08      2
5          2017-09      2

L = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print (L)
[{'Transaction_Date': '2017-04', 'count': 2}, 
 {'Transaction_Date': '2017-05', 'count': 1},
 {'Transaction_Date': '2017-06', 'count': 2},
 {'Transaction_Date': '2017-07', 'count': 1},
 {'Transaction_Date': '2017-08', 'count': 2}, 
 {'Transaction_Date': '2017-09', 'count': 2}]
```

Solution with convert to monthly periods has different list of dicts:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='20D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Transaction_Date': rng})  

df = df.groupby(df['Transaction_Date'].dt.to_period("m")).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df)
  Transaction_Date  count
0          2017-04      2
1          2017-05      1
2          2017-06      2
3          2017-07      1
4          2017-08      2
5          2017-09      2

L = df.to_dict(orient='records')
print (L)
[{'Transaction_Date': Period('2017-04', 'M'), 'count': 2}, 
 {'Transaction_Date': Period('2017-05', 'M'), 'count': 1},
 {'Transaction_Date': Period('2017-06', 'M'), 'count': 2},
 {'Transaction_Date': Period('2017-07', 'M'), 'count': 1},
 {'Transaction_Date': Period('2017-08', 'M'), 'count': 2}, 
 {'Transaction_Date': Period('2017-09', 'M'), 'count': 2}]
```